# editing inlineformset_factory with multiple instance

Tags: django, inline-formset

I have an inline formset with extra=24 which are the hours of the day.
I don't have any issue adding a new entry and saving

```
OreSommInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(FarmacoGiornaliero, OreSomministrazione, 
                                             form=OreForm,  fields=('ore','farmaco', 'quantita'), 
                                             extra=24, can_delete=False)        

myospite = Ospite.objects.filter(cognome=cognome).filter(nome=nome)[0]                 


if request.method == 'POST':                       


    form = GiornalieroForm(request.POST)
    formset = OreSommInlineFormSet(request.POST, prefix='formset')

    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():                           


        giornaliero=form.save(commit=True)      

        for form in formset.forms:
            ora = form.save(commit=False)
            ora.farmaco = giornaliero
            ora.ospite = myospite               
            ora.save()
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can edit and save data of the formset. I have a queryset that returns 24 instances of OreFarmaco which should populate the formset but the formset itself with the instance keyword foresees only one instance.

OreSommInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(FarmacoGiornaliero, OreSomministrazione, 
                                                 form=OreForm, fields=('ore', 'quantita'), 
                                                 extra=24, can_delete=False)

```
myospite = Ospite.objects.filter(cognome=cognome).filter(nome=nome)[0]

locfarmaco = Farmaco.objects.filter(farmaco=farmaco)[0]

giornaliero = FarmacoGiornaliero.objects.select_related() \
            .filter(ospite=myospite) \
            .filter(farmaco=locfarmaco)[0]

orefarmaco = OreSomministrazione.objects.select_related().filter(farmaco=giornaliero).filter(ospite=myospite)           

if request.method == "POST":                      

        form = GiornalieroForm(request.POST, instance=giornaliero)                     

        formset = OreSommInlineFormSet(request.POST, prefix='formset', instance=orefarmaco[0])


        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():                                                             

            giornaliero=form.save(commit=True)   
            formset.save()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try to rewrite this codes it's complicated. Use get() instead
myospite = Ospite.objects.filter(cognome=cognome).filter(nome=nome)[0]
locfarmaco = Farmaco.objects.filter(farmaco=farmaco)[0]
giornaliero = FarmacoGiornaliero.objects.select_related() \
        .filter(ospite=myospite) \
        .filter(farmaco=locfarmaco)[0]
//

if request.method == "POST":                      
    form = GiornalieroForm(request.POST, instance=giornaliero)                     
    if form.is_valid():  
        gio = form.save(commit=True)                                                           
        formset = OreSommInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=gio)
        if formset.is_valid()
            gio.save()   
            formset.save()
```

Comment: when you say get(), you mean use the primary keys or id to retrieve data? My form as a list of 24 extras for formset and the user can change all those values. how could I handle it one by one in the way you are suggesting?

Comment: yeah but you can also use get in all fields. get() function will return one data. Try to change filter to get. For example, like this: myospite = Ospite.objects.get(cognome=cognome, nome=nome)

Comment: ok I'll do that. And what about the formset? Do I have to change my html to fit the cod you suggested?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't see your codes in html. Can you please post it in your question

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain well my question.

Comment: I don't get the reason why if I want to create multiple instance of formset I can do it with
OreSommInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(FarmacoGiornaliero, OreSomministrazione,..... extra=24, can_delete=False)

formset = OreSommInlineFormSet(request.POST, prefix='formset')

but if I want to edit and save multiple formset displayed in one shot on a webpage I can't to do it because I can deal with only one instance at the time

formset = OreSommInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=gio)

There is no other way either to do it?